# Spiral Procedural Texture

Tags: texturing

I cannot figure out how to make a spiral texture, similar to a hurricane, in blender. I tried a wave texture, but I couldn't figure it out. I wish to achieve something like this, and was hoping perhaps you guys could figure it out. I just need a basic shape.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I cannot quite replicate a true wrap but it might be good enough at a distance.
This material uses a Radial Texture to twist some noise textures around a coordinate.

[image: cloud wrap polar twist]

[image: polar texture spiral]

Note that there is a hard edge where the UV twisting stops. I guess you could make a duplicate and offset it by 45 degrees?