# How to make circular material for winding tape

Tags: modeling, texturing, node-editor

How can I make using nodes this type of material - texture, which has circular lines, like sticky tape has, duct tape, cassette, etc etc, it looks like its winded.

[image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/32392/how-can-i-add-banded-lines-to-the-end-of-cinnamon-sticksor-sheets-of-wood/ https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/125206/how-to-twist-radial-vector-to-make-spirals https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/190014/how-do-you-use-texture-to-be-spiraled-or-circular https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/106465/spiral-procedural-texture https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/78379/how-to-twist-a-procedural-material

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can plug a *Texture Coordinate* (*Object* output) into a *Gradient* node (in *Spherical* mode) into a *Wave Texture* node. Play a bit with the *Wave* values in order to make it more natural:

[image]